# Why all item revenue is null in Google Analytics Monetization Ecommerce purchases?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

My site is connected to GA4, but if I watch Monetization Ecommerce purchases, all values are null, but there exist purchases.

[image]

[image]

I add on my site Google tag manager script in the header, but I think can be another JS script added to my site

Comment: sounds like your data layer is wrong.  Make sure your sending the correct ga4 ecommerce datalater object.   Note the currency needs to be correct and the value needs to be numeric

Comment: can you edit your question and include your data layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtm)

Sounds like your dataLayer is wrong double check currency and value they are normally the cause for this issue.

```
dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  // Clear the previous ecommerce object.
dataLayer.push({
  event: "purchase",
  ecommerce: {
      transaction_id: "T_12345",
      value: 25.42,
      tax: 4.90,
      shipping: 5.99,
      currency: "USD",
      coupon: "SUMMER_SALE",
      items: [
       {
        item_id: "SKU_12345",
        item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
        affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
        coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
        discount: 2.22,
        index: 0,
        item_brand: "Google",
        item_category: "Apparel",
        item_category2: "Adult",
        item_category3: "Shirts",
        item_category4: "Crew",
        item_category5: "Short sleeve",
        item_list_id: "related_products",
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        item_variant: "green",
        location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
        price: 9.99,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        item_id: "SKU_12346",
        item_name: "Google Grey Women's Tee",
        affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
        coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
        discount: 3.33,
        index: 1,
        item_brand: "Google",
        item_category: "Apparel",
        item_category2: "Adult",
        item_category3: "Shirts",
        item_category4: "Crew",
        item_category5: "Short sleeve",
        item_list_id: "related_products",
        item_list_name: "Related Products",
        item_variant: "gray",
        location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
        price: 20.99,
        promotion_id: "P_12345",
        promotion_name: "Summer Sale",
        quantity: 1
      }]
  }
});
```